# Office 2010 Professional Plus  Trial - Product Activation Fails

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-office, windows-activation, office-2010-beta

I have installed Office 2010 Professional Plus Beta trial (x64 version) from MSFT site.
Every thing worked fine initially.
But after I rebooted machine (Win7 x64), and started Outlook 2010,  i see an error dialog that I am not in a "corporate network" and the product could not be activated.

I am not in a corporate network. I would like to use Office 2010 on my home network.  How do I get around the Product Activation issue?

Answer (score 1):

Office Professional Plus appears to include Sharepoint and Office Communications Server and Office Mobile components.  These are business applications running on Windows 2008 Server.  If you just want home applications, download only the Office Pro version - not the Pro Plus.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have the wrong version  of the beta. If you downloaded a business version, then that might explain your problem.

Do you have more details please? An Error code or something would help.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. The beta keys eventually expire. Did you try Temporarily downloading the firewall? It may require that is installed on a Windows Enterprise System or Windows Pro Operating System.

In the future:
Short of it being a Work at Home version (Microsoft's Home Use Program) a retail version, (from a store), or an OEM version (pre-installed on a laptop), it may be set up for KMS activation (a complicated thing you don't want to deal with).

**In short:** **Ask your HR department if they have the Microsoft Home Use Program (tell them that you would like a copy of Office 2010 for work purposes if that is what it for (or whatever version they are using on workstation PC's).** Many large organizations do that have a volume licensing agreement. You have to pay $9.95 for the disc *(*buy the backup disc! It will save you many headaches! Also print out your Product key and put it in several places.*)*, but if they offer it it is worth it. Don't think of unauthorized copying of company software, not only will it fail activation, it's illegal).

Alternatively, you could go here and enter your work email to see if you are eligible: http://www.microsofthup.com/hupus/home.aspx

Let me know either way.