# Error code:0x8007007B while activation of MS-Office Pro Plus 2010

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, software-activation

One month ago, I have undergone a virus software attack leading to reset of my pc, all of my files were intact, just applications and features were removed. Then I installed Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010, and now I am getting this notifications regarding activation key. Look at the screenshot below.

[image]

Then, I entered Product key, it was perfectly accepted and the and the installation process was then completed.[image]

[image]

But, then, when I relaunched the programme, it again asked me for activation Key. However times I enter and make my MS product validated, in the very next time, it always shows me that obnoxious *Activation Wizard*.

I have seen [this discussion](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_install/why-do-i-have-to-enter-the-product-key-every-time/c6993f3e-d9b5-4bb2-9a09-83ae7f30cc0c), none of the workarounds suggested there, worked for me. I never got an *run as administrator* option upon right click, which was one of the suggestions stated there.

Also, followed some discussions like [this](https://superuser.com/questions/375850/office-2010-pro-plus-install-failure-setup-cannot-find-proplusr-ww-proprww2-ca), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/358796/ms-office-2010-professional-plus-change-product-key-error) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/80688/office-2010-professional-plus-trial-product-activation-fails), but those are different problems.

Just the link of discussion in MS site was reasonable, but that didn't solve my problem.

Any way out?

Comment: I added (windows-10) tag only because I am using windows 10 pro OS. If this tag is irrelevant, then feel free to edit and remove the tag.

Comment: Are you an administrator on your computer?

Comment: @TheKB, yes, I am.